# Ubuntu 14.04 hangs on purple screen

Tags: ubuntu

I have Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot on my laptop. (Ubuntu is a recent installation.) Windows works fine, but Ubuntu hangs at the purple screen when I try to boot it. The laptop has a NVidia video card and I've been using it for GPU computations on Ubuntu quite a bit lately. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First open Ubuntu console using

```
Ctrl-Alt-F1
```

Then remove nVidia drivers

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

After doing this use following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-xxx
```

please use your nVidia driver model for xxx, for more details follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433) thread, and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454729/installed-14-04-and-nvidia-graphics-card-wont-load) if you are having more problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary that you can have this problem for Nvidia. I don't have Nvidia, but I still got this problem, which I solved by following these steps.

The following steps should be taken:

1. Check that you can still do this at startup:

   Hold down (or repeatedly tap) the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while you boot. GRUB should present you with a menu. Choose the second option, to go into Recovery mode, then select *Drop to root shell prompt*.
2. Look for the log of removed packages. In the terminal you can input the following code:

   ```
   sudo gedit /var/log/apt/history.log
   ```
3. Find the removed packages and then run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install package1 package2 package3
   ```
4. If confirmed through vim almost a screen full of uninstalled packages for example `xserver-xorg-video-s3-lts-raring, xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse`

   Thus to install the uninstalled packages, use a command like this example:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-s3-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse  ## Add more packages to the end of the command as required.
   ```

*Note:* Always have a space as a delimiter character between package1 package2 etc.